# Why is the media query not working on mobile?

Tags: html, media

I used a media query in my html page. Both for small screens and greater than 500px. here is a sample.

```html
.col-1 { width: 58%;}
.col-2 {width: 25%;}
.col-3 {width: 16%;}
.col-4 {width: 100%;}


@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
 .col-sm-1 {width: 100%;}
 }
 
 
 <body>
 <div class="header col-4 col-sm-1"></div>
 <div class="aside col-2 col-sm-1"></div>
 <div class="main col-1 col-sm-1"></div>
 <div class="right-col col-3 col-sm-1"></div>
 <div class="footer col-4 col-sm-1">
```

When I resize browser's window to below 480px , all divs  width change to 100%.
but I transfer that file to my mobile , and when open the file in mobile browser , the width does not change to 100%. however zoom level is good (good readable)

Comment: Please remember to mention which version of any frameworks you are using. Such as bootstrap 3 / 4.

Comment: I am not using any framework. I am using notepad++

Comment: Surely you want max-width: 480px if you only want the rule to apply below 480px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col-sm-1 {width: 100%;}
 }
```

This will only apply a width of 100% when the screen is 480px or below.

If still no joy then try:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .col-1,
  .col-2,
  .col-3 {
  width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {`

needs to be

`@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {`

Comment: sorry , i added wrote @medai in webpage , but i forget to type @